# C# Calculate datetime difference during object initialization from LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have the below code running fine, it returns data from SQL tables:

```
    List<TypeA> Class1 = ( from rec in Entity.Context.Table  select new Class1
                      { NAME = rec.name,
                        FIRSTDATE = rec.firstdate,
                        LASTDATE = rec.lastdate

                         //my func CalcTimeDiff, doesnt work
                          ElapsedMin = CalcTimeDiff(LASTDATE, FIRSTDATE) 

                       }).ToList();
public class Class1
{
   public string  NAME = {get; set;}
   public Nullable<DateTime> FIRSTDATE = {get; set;}
   public Nullable<DateTime> LASTDATE = {get; set;}
   public int ElapsedMin = {get; set;}

   // My function to calculate time difference
    public int CalcTimeDiff ( DateTime A, DateTime B)
          {
              TimeSpan Diff = A - B;
              int MinElapsed = (int)Diff.TotalMinutes;
              return MinElapsed;
            }
}
```

What I'am looking for is to add method to calculate DateTime difference between LASTDATE and FIRSTDATE to the Class1 class and invoke it in Class1 initialization. But still no luck, getting errors I cannot use non-static fields... Any idea how to get it managed?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve here. I would *definitely* advise you to start following normal .NET naming conventions though.

Comment: You could use a constructor and call the method inside of it

Comment: Those properties don't compile.

Comment: `from rec .... where select new Class1` i doubt you have that code running fine

Comment: and there is also a comma (`,`) missing after `LASTDATE = rec.lastdate`. In Visual Studio it is easy to format your code. Just press Ctrl-E-D.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you need `ElapsedMin` to be settable (I can't see why you would), just make it a calculated property:

```
public int ElapsedMin => CalcTimeDiff(FirstDate, LastDate);
```

or

```
public int ElapsedMin => (int)(LastDate - FirstDate).Value.TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: .TotalMinutes cannot be applied here. That would be TimeSpan class to have it available..

Comment: @smirQ True. Use the edited version if you don't care about checking for nulls. Otherwise use first version and check for nulls.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking out something like this.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }

    public Nullable<DateTime> FIRSTDATE { get; set; }

    public Nullable<DateTime> LASTDATE { get; set; }

    public int ElapsedMin { get; set; }


    public Class1(DateTime LD, DateTime FD)
    {
        TimeSpan Diff = LD - FD;
        this.ElapsedMin = (int)Diff.TotalMinutes;
    }

}
```

public class Class2

```
{

    public void Test()

    {

        Class1 c1 = new Class1(DateTime.Now ,Convert.ToDateTime("01-23-1992"));
        int elapsedMin = c1.ElapsedMin;

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you'r doing is a little messy. Carefull wit nullables.

```
var resultList = (from rec
                      in recordList
                      select new Class1
                      {
                          NAME = rec.name,
                          FIRSTDATE = rec.firstdate,
                          LASTDATE = rec.lastdate,
                          ElapsedMin = (int)(rec.lastdate.Value  - rec.firstdate.Value).TotalMinutes
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: There is NO .Value method available on rec.lastdate or rec.firstdate. These are DateTime SQL Table columns references I beleive..

Comment: If they are DateTime SQL Table columns and the fields are marked as NULL this subtractions is not going to work, This is why I set them as nullable for this example, nullable fields have the .Value property. If they are not nullable just remove the .Value and this linq query will work. Once again carefull with DBNulls